# parametric equation of a line through point of projection

Tags: projection

[with regard to my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756412/coordinate-positions-along-the-perspective-projection-line?noredirect=1#comment7726743_3756412)  which says:

[image]

We can write equations describin coordinate positions along this perspective projection line in parametric form as:

$$ x' = x-xu \\ y'=y-yu\\z'=z-(z-z_{prp})u
$$

I've made a 3D illustration as per my understanding of the concept:

[image]

Is my illustration accurately depicting the equations?